# Power BI - Problem creating Moving Average (600k Rows)

Tags: powerbi, moving-average

I tried to calculate a moving average over the last 3 observations by using an index. Neither the use of "earlier"

```
Moving_Average = 
calculate(
    sum([var1]) / sum([var2]), 
    filter(
        'table', 
        earlier('table'[Index]) > 'table'[Index]-3 
        && earlier('table'[Index]) <= 'table'[Index]
    )
)
```

nor the introduction of a variable helped.

```
Moving_Average2 = 
var thisindex = 'table'[Index]

return
calculate(
    sum([var1]) / sum([var2]), 
    filter( 
        'table', 
        'table'[Index] > thisindex-3 
        && 'table'[Index] <= thisindex
    )
)
```

Power BI tells me it's working on it but even after 1 hour, it's not done. The problem might be the size of the table with ~600k rows. Is there a way to do it in a timely manner?

Comment: What’s your data source? Is the report using DirectQuery or Import mode? In case of the variable formula, is that a column or a measure?

Comment: The data comes from a csv, the index gets created during the import in Power BI. It's Import mode, and the variable formula is a column.

Comment: Those codes belongs to Measure or Custom Column?

Comment: Those are Custom Columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out! Create a **measure** with below DAX.

```
Moving Average = 
VAR currentIndex = MAX(Data[Index])
VAR movingAverage = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Column1]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Data), Data[Index] > currentIndex - 3 && Data[Index] <= currentIndex))
return movingAverage
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your result with the MAX. It works for me without the MAX but the calculations in the large file take too long like mentioned in the OP.

Comment: I forgot to mention. Can you try creating a measure instead of a calculated column?

Comment: Excellent! It works and it's a better approach to just calculate the few values I'm interested in on the fly instead of having all 600k moving averages calculated at once.